# Dell Laptop Powering On When Lid Is Opened

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, power-management, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop with factory-installed Windows 8, upgraded to Windows 8.1, and later to Windows 10.  Since I have purchased a new computer, I decided to perform a factory reset on the laptop (using the *Remove files and clean the drive* option) in order to repurpose it.

It reset flawlessly on the first try in about 5-6 hours, and runs perfectly now, but with only one issue introduced after the reset that wasn't present before:  the laptop now powers itself on from a shut-down state upon opening the lid, as opposed to opening the lid and then pressing the power button (this occurs on both battery and power).  To add on to that, there was even an instance where the lid was already *open* and the laptop was completely shut down, and opening the lid just a little bit *more* turned the laptop back on too!  Very strange, but this hasn't happened more than once yet.

I've tried turning off the *Fast Startup* option from the Control Panel and also applying the *Do Nothing* setting to both the power button and lid closed; both didn't solve the issue.  I also can't find a BIOS setting that has to do with it.  My shutdown process is clicking Start, then Power, then Shut Down.

Main question:  **How can I stop the laptop from powering on when the lid is opened, but rather require pushing the power button only?**

Upon doing research on this, I've seen that most other people with this issue have Toshiba laptops, which tend to have a BIOS setting that enables and disables this specific feature, but I don't seem to have it, and I can't find any other solution that has worked.  If you need any more information about my laptop, configuration, or settings, please let me know.  I appreciate all assistance.

Comment: I saw this when fastStartup is used. Disable the fastStartup of windows in the power options

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I mentioned that I already tried to turn off Fast Startup, and this does not fix the issue.  I just tried it again and it still did not work.